# error TS2345: Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Y>'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't know how to fix this problem,

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'BookUpdateParseInput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Book>'.
  Types of property 'author' are incompatible.
    Type 'Author | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | (() => string) | undefined'.
      Type 'Author' is not assignable to type 'number | (() => string) | undefined'.
        Type 'Author' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
          Type 'Author' provides no match for the signature '(): string'.

114                 await this.bookRepository.update(bookId.id, await this.parseInput(input));
```

**This is the part of the code where i have this problem**

```
@Mutation(()=> Boolean)
        async updateBookById(
            @Arg('bookId',()=> BookIdInput) bookId: BookIdInput,
            @Arg ('input',()=> BookUpdateInput) input: BookUpdateInput,
        ): Promise<Boolean>{
            try{
                await this.bookRepository.update(bookId.id, await this.parseInput(input));
                return true;
            }catch(e){
                throw new Error(e)
            }
        }
```

Comment: It says Author is undefined and undefined cant be used in the call.

Comment: It looks like your `parseInput` returns the fields of the author instead of just the author ID. You need to resolve to the author ID and pass that instead.